# Stylesheet error on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, stylesheet

My stylesheet is not working on chrome. It gives an error such as:

Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mrv/Desktop/Results/TruvaResultsStyleSheet.xsl from frame with URL file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mrv/Desktop/Results/LatLon_test.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Need to use a web server.

Comment: try installing a web server like wamp .and execute it from localhost

Answer (score 0):

Load your document, and stylesheet over HTTP. Install a web server on your development machine if you need to.

Comment: Because they put less effort into protecting people from trojan HTML documents.